# Node gets wrong HTML from package.json when executing npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` file that looks like:

```
{
  "name": "assignment-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is the Git and Node basic learning project",
  "main": "aboutus.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://path_to_git/first-assignment.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://path_to_git/first-assignment#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://path_to_git/first-assignment/issues"
  },
```

but when I execute `npm start`, instead of `aboutus.html`, the `index.html` webpage opens.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and I don't get the `aboutus.html` loading as I want it to?

Comment: That is the default behaviour. Where did you configure aboutus.html ?

Comment: aboutus.html and index.html are in the same git folder. I want to open aboutus.html when I type npm start, but instead index.html opens. How can I open aboutus.html instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution:

The `index.html` appears as the default page, in `localhost:3000`. Then I simply need to write `localhost:3000/aboutus.html` to get to the page I wanted to go... Seems like it was pretty simple after all!